# Refresh parts pf page every minute with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh

I'm trying to run this code, but it's only loading blank content into my element. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to load the current page (that might contain changes since it was loaded the last time and fetch some elements from it and replace those elements on the page without reloading the entire document in the browser window.)

```
function refreshContent(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Can this be replaced with JS? ?>",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response != 0)
            {
                var data = $.parseHTML(response);
                $('body').replaceWith($(data).find('body'));
            }
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    refreshContent();
}, 60000);
```

My Response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head id="page">... with body and all of that
```

Comment: what does your response look like ?

Comment: @TimCodes Original post updated with response...

Comment: try this document.write(data); or document.write(response);

Comment: @TimCodes I think the `parseHTML` (is it even needed?) and the `$(data).find('body')` part is not working. document.write(data); only refreshes the whole thing two times, and then dies.

Comment: may be it's better to update the needed parts of the page, not the whole page ? it seems you try to  imitate META refresh.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Yeah, that's what I want to do! Body will be a different element later, I'm just using it here now to get it working. Ideas?

Comment: Give an ID to the needed area for the page element, and update content for that element. Instead of BODY at all, also with the URL for your AJAX call - it'll be better to get not the page but needed data json encoded at server. If you can explain and also show what actually you want to have I think I can then help  you

Comment: Sure, you're right. I should probably fetch just what's needed. Tried to take a shortcut. But, would be great to find out how I can reach a node inside my full page load? To put it simple. How do I load the entire page and get only the element, let's say, #content into a variable from that response? Am I on the right track with parseHTML?

Comment: `$.ajax({url:` should be a different page.

Comment: @Vyacheslav `$('#content').load('<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> #content', function(){});` Is almost doing what I want, but it puts the new #content inside of the old, not replacing it. Thoughts?

Comment: @Vyacheslav This works the way I want!! `$.get("<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>", function(data) { $("#content").replaceWith($(data).find("#content")); });`

Comment: I'm glad to see you on the right way :) Do you need any guidance to fall into that deeply ?

Comment: Please check this from jquery official documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/